# How do I respond to click events from a button in a custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-custom-view, buttonclick

I'm trying to adapt [this tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) for use with a `TextView` and `Button`. I've created my `ArrayList` and `ListView`:

```
   private void displayListView() {

    //putting two Country objects into the ArrayList
    //these countries have email addresses for some reason, just go with it
    ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    country = new Country("email@email.com","DummyName1",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("email@email.com","DummyName2",false);
    countryList.add(country);

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.pending_invite, countryList);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPendingRequests);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

Here is my main XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">  

         <ListView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/listViewPendingRequests" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `pending_invite.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Pending Invitation 1"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickCancel"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I think I'm having trouble making `MyCustomAdapter` given that I'm no longer looking for checkboxs and stuff. Anyway, this is what I've got so far:

```
 private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        Button name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.pending_invite, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.name = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Country country = countryList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.name.setTag(country);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

So that works (surprisingly) to construct the views, but how do I tell which one was pressed in the onClick?:

```
 public void onClickCancel(View view){
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OnClickCancel view: " + view.getId()); //getId returns the same thing for all clicks. How do I get which button clicked?

}
```

The `view.getId` returns the same ID for all any of the buttons. How do I attach an onClick Listener to inflated buttons within a custom view?

Comment: "For all buttons" you mean each object from the adapter list ? Each country in this case ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Each `"DummyName"` is being displayed as text on the `Button` from pending_invite.xml - I want to know which one of those inflated buttons was clicked.

Comment: It will be better to add an oncliklistener throough code.

Comment: @Age check my answer, you will get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        Button name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.pending_invite, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.name = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Country country = countryList.get(position);
       // holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        //holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(countryList.get(position).getName());     // here you are setting the tag, it will be retrieved in handleClick method
        // here create your on click handler, like

       holder.name.setOnClickListener(handleClick(holder.name));


        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Here define your `handleClick` method

```
private OnClickListener handleClick(final Button butn) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String TAG = butn.getTag().toString();  // get the tag, now you can compare which button has been clicked with respect to its tag name 

             if (TAG.equals("somehting")
             {
                  // your logic here
             }
            }
        };
    }
```

I hope you got some idea from this answer.

Comment: Thanks! It detects the click event, but the `TAG` is not consistent and is giving me something that looks like this: `ca.mypackage.Country@42ac05d0`  Am I supposed to be saving the TAG somewhere when it's generated to compare later?

Comment: Try changing `holder.name.setTag(country);` to `holder.name.setTag(countryList.get(position).getName());`. If this didn't work then please post `Country` class.

Comment: You're a champ! Thank you very much for your help, I actually understand how this is working a lot better. I have changed the setTag portion in your answer to the code that you just described in the last comment (it worked!). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Filed "ID" in the class Country. Then assign a value for each object while creating instances of Country. Then add an onclick listener inside the class country for the button, passing the position. then use the below function to get the click

```
public void onClickCancel(int position){

Country country = countryList.get(position);

String countryId = country.ID;
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OnClickCancel view: " + countryId ); 
}
```

Comment: `public void onClickCancel(int position){` is invalid. onClick events from the xml can only receive 1  View argument. Or are you saying I'm allowed to make a listener and change this somehow?

Comment: I do not mean this function to be called from xml, but from onClickListener of the Custom Class

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;
    private Context context;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList =countryList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        Button name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pending_invite, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.name = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(countryList.get(position).getName());
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,countryList.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(handleClick(holder.name));

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry to be a bother, but could you please share your `handleClick` method? I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with that part.

Comment: Copy of my answer. Instead of this you could have up voted my answer. This is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: @Aniruddha,have you doesn't seen any difference in my and your ans ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch onClick for button only,you must implement onClickListener for your button : holder.name

holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

if you want to get which item is clicked, setOnItemClickListener for your listview . or just setOnClickListener for your customView 
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```